# Print function isn't working properly- Linked list

Tags: c++, algorithm, linked-list

I am new to the data structures and I was trying to write a code which add nodes to the beginning of the linked list. After every time user enters a new node, the program is supposed to display an updates linked list, but my program is only displaying the current entered node.

The code is as follows: -

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
struct Node
{
  int data;
  Node* next;
};
struct Node* head;

void Insert(int x) 
{
  Node* temp=new Node();
  temp->data=x;
  temp->next=NULL;
  head=temp;
}

void Print()
{
  struct Node* temp=head;
  cout<<"List is: ";
  while(temp!=NULL)
  {
    cout<<temp->data;
    temp=temp->next;
  }
  cout<<"\n";
}  

void main()
{
  head=NULL;
  clrscr();
  cout<<"How many numbers?\n";
  int n,x,i;
  cin>>n;
  for(i=0; i<n; i++) 
  {
    cout<<"Enter the number \n";
    cin>>x;
    Insert(x);
    Print();
  }
  getch(); 
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that the print function is at fault? Why don't you suspect e.g. the inserting function?

Comment: After you've inserted a node, `head` points to the new node, and the new node's `next` pointer is null. How many elements are there in the list?

Comment: @ALOKKUMAR take a look at the answer and accept the one that suits you the most

Answer (score 0):

Your `Insert` method is wrong. You need to assign `head` to `next`:

```
void Insert(int x) 
{
  Node* temp=new Node();
  temp->data=x;
  temp->next=head;
  head=temp;
}
```

This will then chain your list correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Insert` function is wrong. You need to use something like this in order to add  new items at the end of the list:

```cpp
void InsertAtTheEnd(int x)  {
    Node* temp = new Node();
    temp->data=x;
    temp->next=NULL;
    if (NULL == head) {
        head = temp;
    } else {
        Node *tmp = head;
        while (tmp->next != NULL) {
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        tmp->next = temp;
    }
}
```

And this will add them to the beggining:

```cpp
void InsertAtTheBeginning(int x)  {
    Node* temp=new Node();
    temp->data=x;
    temp->next=head;
    head=temp;
}
```

Check it out [live](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tLgDZSW9ABk8tTADljAI0zEQAdlIAHVAsLqtHqGJuY%2BfgF0tvZORq7uXkoqanQMBMzEBMHGppwWSZiqgWkZBNGOLm6eiumZ2aF5NaXlsfGeAJSKqAbEyBwA5FIAzHbIhljiQzrqCgTEmMxGk9jiAAwAgmvrBv6iANS0i5gK3sx9e7Pok7IbW7PEBqp7DhiYe%2BIeN%2Bt7P3t2BHt0Mx0tctr9nq8AFQHTAADwIoNuHgAIojNht7o8AS8sNCEAsrkMvlsAG6oPDoPYASVoSky6wIABV8dhtBB/ntYe13p8wb8cZhoQRMEZvO8hsiYQB3CFYCDtNHg4WigC0yyBIIlsMVv2V3jVQ1ZcIREocAFVrNYdT88FQ9hBzZbxaiJXt8cx0NyPl9weD3ZTJpK9daeZLlEoeT7fT8BXtIQRRc63QSQ%2BCpQg8Ox7Qn9ct7PC9mAwIHnhbrF7eRto9Gc0mcwajfDU78Pqiq9X63njXWRd4Q62tgPbhsyRTqbS3AQGczMNJMMA7LQ7MB2fRORWozGoXtgxL7DKBfKQ3qGxrmIHtUS%2BT8T12mxL/SHHxLd8SUYOR%2BTKQAFYj/eWRteFxzFisqCjuvaBs%2Bm57GgBgApMOiIe8kiSLYsx/AoIAoZIIbppmbwQHqhbFq6jrloB7bRnBCFTMht6Gme4pIVMOE4c2N69j2qp3iaMFDt8vw0YhImoeIACsOi0FIuFXkibbousHJGMwdgAd6QHPsi5FokBNJ0lOTIsmynAKnJgk/Ppk7TsZ6AQJIZkwVZ9JGbO86LsuEBDI5QG/v%2BPnDhZezzAQPS0Hsqy6Si/SdKwID9OJ/SkKY/SrElqDxUhMhyBc3S9G8wycElBDxWl7SdAA1iA3AAJwAHQABzibV3BmEMQyrDwkiNHF/TcElKVpaQGX9ElWGrKQJWpTFpBwLAMCICgqCigRZAUBAaArew7jADVkikFQmbCsQWEQM4pVJc4dgZAAnvFRWkJtRhaAQADytCsHd02kFgKmiOwF0/Xg8xFCSxyA3ChTwQMQ3/MogOsHgzjELdehYPdxV/kYGOdDQ9BMGwHA8PwID7cIogoHIchCEjWGQJ0qDeCktLxSqlyBhI2UyJIzBjcohTM5o2j1LkljaC0lTuJw4T%2BMzIuCL4suBBLcRVNLBRFKktRZPoOSCBrzMlJkKttOr2vy2bzR2BUqtS50Ch5X0XCxfFiXJYDI2wg1ZgqmY3B7MAyDIHs9WSPauCECQKFDNLex6FtbjRw5cdUzIxUXeVpBVeJqx1TwOfiUMZhmDVTUeA13DiUI8X9aQ2M5%2B730jWNIATVNZWzQtEBIN0BDePB5CUJt3iraTlj4EQUsHXQjAsADxNSij3g49XCUDR78XDGHUqEAgnLe77/uB8Hofp9Nmf%2BlU8qr7X9cTYN6XxS3bcZ5VIA53nlerIXxel%2BJ5eV1XkMdeTcn6TVfqvSQIChrN3AefToYMTqBGqkAA)

Comment: Thank you so much! I found the solution through you answer

Comment: @ALOKKUMAR you may want to upvote and accept my answer (green tick beneath the votes)